# How to append an element inside object using a common way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object called "x" and the format is given below:

```
var x = [{
name: "a",
item:[{
    name: "b",
    item:[{
        name: "c",
        item:[{
            name:"f"
        }]
    },{
    name: "d",
    item:[{
        name: "e"
        }]
    }]
}]
},{
    name: "a",
    item:[{
        name: "b",
        item:[{
            name: "c"
        }]
    }]
}];
```

and now i push some element inside this object. For example:

```
x[0].item[0].name = "x";
x[0].item[0].item[0].name = "y";
x[0].item[0].item[0].item[0].name = "z";
```

So, Here is my question. I pushed three element inside the object. The code for that is given above and all the three code are similar, only the number of "items" is changed. Example: in 1st code, only one "item" is used and in the next, two "items" and next,three items.

So, is there any efficient way to create a common function to push the element inside the object (or) like in Array, can we push like `x[0].items[[0][0]] = "y"`. ?

Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/o7Ldtmpj/).

Comment: What do you mean by "common function?" It is possible to write a simple function that does what you want, but there isn't anything built into the language to do that.

Comment: I think you can't achieve something like `x[0].items[[0][0]] = "y"`, from [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859399/override-a-objects-bracket-index-getter-setter-in-javascript).

Comment: Just to get your terminology straight and perhaps make this question a little less confusing, what you did with your three lines of code is you "assigned three properties to existing objects".  You did not "push some element" by any common programming definition of those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version without error handling**

Preliminary note: I assume, that you always have `[n]` or `[n].item[m]` structure. The algorithm does not have any error handling.

The needed array is evaluated as follows: Take the first element and get the object. Get the next element and before applying the element get the `item` property first. Then apply the array index. Repeat. After finishing the loop apply the value to the `name` property.

```js
var x=[{name:"a",item:[{name:"b",item:[{name:"c",item:[{name:"f"}]},{name:"d",item:[{name:"e"}]}]}]},{name:"a",item:[{name:"b",item:[{name:"c"}]}]}];

function push(o, a, v) {
    a.forEach(function (el, i) {
        i && (o = o.item);
        o = o[el];
    });
    o.name = v;
}

push(x, [0, 0, 0], 'y');
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

**Version with error handling**

Assuming nothing. If not well formed it throws exception when property `item` is not given or index of array is out of bound.

```js
var x=[{name:"a",item:[{name:"b",item:[{name:"c",item:[{name:"f"}]},{name:"d",item:[{name:"e"}]}]}]},{name:"a",item:[{name:"b",item:[{name:"c"}]}]}];

function getReference(o, a) {
    a.forEach(function (el, i) {
        if (i) {
            if ('item' in o) {
                o = o.item;
            } else {
                throw new Error('No Reference (item)');
            }
        }
        if (o[el]) {
            o = o[el];
        } else {
            throw new Error('No Reference (index: ' + el + ')');
        }
    });
    return o;
}

 // working
try {
    getReference(x, [0, 0, 0, 0]).name = 'z';
} catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}

// throws exception 'No Reference (index: 3)'
try {
    getReference(x, [0, 0, 0, 3]).name = '*';
} catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the code for "version without error control" - can you explain it?

Comment: yes, the version without error handling does not check whether item or indexed element exists. the other version throws an exception if the object is not well formed.